# Why does Nmap use out of range source port numbers?

Tags: ubuntu, nmap

I've read that the following are the correct standard IPv4 port numbers:

```
0 -  1023 Well known ports
```

1024 - 49151 Registered ports

49152 – 65535 Dynamic ports

However, when I use the client nmap (nmap.org), with Ubuntu 18.04, the source port is 34305, 34306, etc.  I would expect the source port to be in the dynamic port range.  Is this a bug in nmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a "bug" per se, just Nmap choosing to ignore some standards in favor of having more source ports available to work with. Nmap makes lots of connections to lots of endpoints, and tries to optimize its speed to avoid dropped packets. To do this, it must be able to identify how long between the time a probe is sent and the time a response is received. If it sends the same probe twice before the response to the first probe is received, it can think the network is twice as fast as it really is. To avoid this, it [encodes an identifier into the source port](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/ec30dbab3f519f91bf6b66653b5c44187cae5a13/scan_engine_raw.cc#L241-L278) in order to not mix up responses and get the most accurate timing information. Because it sends so many probes, it tries to avoid looping back over the same source port by increasing the range of possible values. You can see in the code I linked where it chooses ports above 33000.